# Correct way to use a DataGrid when utilizing a LINQ2SQL DataContext table as its ItemsSource (best practices)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, datagrid

So, I am learning Linq2SQL by building a simple UI.  I am using two DataGrids to display a master/details type interface, where "Customers" are displayed in one grid and, when selected, some details displayed in the other grid (for example, records from a foreign key table such as "Orders", whatever).

Now, every example I have read regarding the use of a DataGrid shows something like this:

```
using( var db = new TestDataContext() )
{
    // AutoGenerateColumns set to false and 
    // column bindings set to certain properties 
    // of the Customer class.
    grid.ItemsSource = db.Customers.ToList();
}
```

Well, that doesn't work because the DataContext is accessed after this code is executed due to data binding, and of course, the Context object has already been disposed.  Ok, that's fine; I can use a single DataContext for all of my grid operations, even though the DataContext class was designed to be used and disposed of quickly.  I'm not sure if keeping a single DataContext around is going to bite me in the future yet.

So now I run into the issue of updating the database and reflecting those changes back to the grid(s).  The simplest way I have come across is to set `ItemsSource` to null and then bind it once again to the table.  This just feels 'dirty' to me and I have to imagine I am missing something.   In theory I could use an ObservableCollection and bind that to the grid, keeping it in sync with the underlying data, but I haven't yet figured out how to get the grid to display data from the observable collection (I bind it in XAML and only empty rows are rendered in the table).

**TLDR:**

So anyway, my question is this; what patterns do you experienced LINQ2SQL guys use for this type of a scenario?  It seems that all of the examples I can find are overly simplistic and don't quite apply in a real world use case (even one as simple as mine).  Basically, how do you use your DataContext, how do you keep the grid updated when new items are added to a table, and what are some general best practices here?

Comment: Do not use a singleton `DataContext`! Problems will ensue should you pursue it. I wish I knew enough to explain exactly _why_ and _what_, however all I can assert is of experience - and it broke, at least in the web world (won't go into specifics here). Which garden you playing in?

Comment: That's kinda what I figured, but I don't see another option if I want to use a DataGrid.  This is my question :).  The app itself is WPF, non-web.

Answer (score 2):

In the example code you provided, the datacontext would only be getting accessed again by bindings if you are binding to lazily loaded properties.
Have you looked at the LoadOptions.LoadWith<>() function on the datacontext (assuming it hasn't been renamed since I last looked at linqtosql)

Personally I have no problem taking a hold of the datacontext and keeping it around for the page life, though not a single one for the whole application life.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `LoadWith`, I didn't know about that.  This is a desktop app, so there is no 'page life', only application life.  Any thoughts on the grid updating question?  What I am doing now feels like a workaround, I am assuming there is a better way to go about keeping each grid up to date.

Comment: ObservableCollection is the only wany to get them to update automatically when rows are added or removeed. Not sure why you are getting empty rows, there must be something wrong with the binding expression in the XAML.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to take another look.  The binding itself is simple: `ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"`, where Customers is an observable collection.  I get n number of empty rows when I set the property, where n corresponds to the number of elements in the collection.  So, rows are added, they're just empty.  Not sure why as a List works fine.